# The checkboxes after they are checked lose their listeners in jquery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Here is my code in a rails view:

```
<div class="lists">
  <h1>Your Todo Lists</h1>
  <div class="incomplete-list">
    <p>This is the incomplete list</p>
    <% @incomplete_list.items.each do |item| %>
    <div class="incomplete-item">
      <%= form_for :item, url: item_path(item), method: :post, html: { class: "item-box" } do |f|%>
        <%= f.label item.title %>
        <%= f.check_box item.id %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="complete-list">
    <p>This is the completed list</p>
    <% @complete_list.items.each do |item| %>
    <div class="complete-item">
      <%= form_for :item, url: item_path(item), method: :post, html: { class: "item-box" } do |f|%>
        <%= f.label item.title %>
        <%= f.check_box item.id %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var changeDom = function(itemRow) {
      var parentList = itemRow.parent()
      itemRow.remove()
      // I am so dumb, you can't remove an itemRow first and then ask for its parent. You dumb dumb. It's [] if you
      // ask for the parent after you remove it. So you need to set it first with var parent =
      if (parentList.attr("class") === "incomplete-list") {
        $(".complete-list").append(itemRow)
      }
      else {
        $(".incomplete-list").append(itemRow)
      }
    }

    var itemLists = $(".lists")
    itemLists.find(":checkbox").on("change", function(box){
      var box = $(this)
      var item_number = parseInt(box[0].name.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)[0])
      $.ajax( { type: "PUT",
          url: "items/" + item_number,
          data: { id: item_number },
          success: function(text) {
            changeDom($(box[0].closest("div")))
          }
        });
      })
    })
</script>
```

It works the first time. I render this page with incomplete-items and complete-items. But after I click them and after they jump from one list to the other...they lose their listeners and no longer work. What does one do?

Also how do I get it so when an incomplete box is checked, it is checked in the other list and when a checked box is in the complete-list, it becomes unchecked in the other.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove a dom element, then yes, it's listeners will be removed too.

There are two things you could do:

1. Your `changeDom` function could be modified so it doesn't remove the element, but rather it should *move* the element from one list to another.  If you move the element, then the listeners will still be bound.

   Look at the `detach` method in jQuery, as a way to move an element, but keep it's listeners bound

   https://api.jquery.com/detach/
2. But a better approach, which is more efficent, is to not actually bind the events to each checkbox / row in your list.

   Instead, use event delegation to bind a click event at a higher level. Which is more efficent, as you are not having to create listeners for each checkbox. Instead there is just one listener for the entire list - but it will still respond to clicks for each checkbox.

   ```
   $(".lists").on("change", ":checkboxes", function() {
      // do stuff
   });
   ```

   Because you are listening for events at a higher level, it won't matter if you move the checkbox elements around - no event listeners will be disrupted.

   Here is some documentation on event delegation:

   https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) which will remove the attached event handlers and data

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed

In your case since the element is added to one or another element after the remove, there is no need to call `remove()` you can just append it to the target element

```
var changeDom = function (itemRow) {
    var parentList = itemRow.parent()
    if (parentList.attr("class") === "incomplete-list") {
        $(".complete-list").append(itemRow)
    } else {
        $(".incomplete-list").append(itemRow)
    }
}
```

If you still want to follow the same flow, use [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

```
var changeDom = function (itemRow) {
    var parentList = itemRow.parent()
    itemRow.detach()
    if (parentList.hasClass("incomplete-list")) {
        $(".complete-list").append(itemRow)
    } else {
        $(".incomplete-list").append(itemRow)
    }
}
```